# Why does compiler not perform implicit conversion, when first operand is not a class object (member function operator overloading)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Let's conside the following member function:

```
Rational operator + ( const Rational & ) const;  //Rational is the class name
```

Complier translates `a + b` to `a.operator+(b)`

**case 1:** a + 14  //a is `Rational` class object.
This works fine, because 14 is implicitly converted to class type `Rational`  (Am I correct ?)

**case 2:** 14 + a // a is a `Rational` class object.
This does not work because 14 is not a `Rational` class object.

My question : Why does the compiler not perform impicit conversion in case 2?

Comment: You may want to add `language-lawyer` tag, since the answer will probably involve a lot of standard-ese.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not make the assumption that operators are commutative. In order for `x + a` to work there must either be a built in operator `+` that is applicable (not the case), a user defined member operator of `x` that is applicable (not the case; `int` does not have members) or a operator defined outside of the class (seems to be missing in this case).

None of those cases applies for `14 + a` which is why this fails. You could implement the operator outside of the class though to make this expression work:

```
class Rational
{
public:
    Rational operator + ( const Rational & ) const;
...
};

template<typename T>
Rational operator+(T o1, Rational const& o2)
{
    return Rational(o1) + o2;
}
```